# hls streaming m3u8 from local html page on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, blob, http-live-streaming

I am trying to use hls streaming (using hls.js library). I have it working in a Visual Studio project, using localhost.

HTML:

```
    <video id="video"></video>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, function () {            
        hls.loadSource('http://<the url>/hls/all.m3u8');            
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function (event, data) {            
            video.play();
        });
    });
```

However, my requirement is to be calling my html page locally (i.e., file:///C:/Users/...), not from a server. When I pull up my html page that way, it doesn't work.

1. I feel like it has something to do with the http protocol that doesn't happen when I view the page locally, but I'm not really sure and I can't explain it well. Can someone explain why this doesn't work?
2. Is there a way that I can stream from the hls m3u8 URL locally?

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT: I should have included the error I get when trying to run locally. It is:

> Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/07b24af7-ede2-49e3-9653-c46335166f34

Comment: does a plain video tag without the lib work? if not, then you're answer is probably "no". you could probably use an iframe to wrap copepen preview or something else online and free...

Comment: which one is local, html or m3u8?

Comment: When I use localhost (running the VS project normally) in Chrome, it streams successfully from the 'http:// ... all.m3u8' url (sorry I can't share the URL). The same exact html markup/javascript does not work when I pull up the html directly (file:///c:/Users/<path>/home.html) in Chrome.